# Plot single-axis data?

Tags: plot, command-line-interface, gnuplot

I have a long list of Linux timestamps, representing the second that events occurred over a one-hour period (3600 seconds). Most events are separated by 3-4 seconds but some are separated by one second and some happen at the same second:

```
1371995100
1371995103
1371995106
1371995106
1371995107
1371995109
1371995111
1371995113
1371995114
1371995118
1371995121
```

I would like to plot this data as a series of lines representing "event happened", as such (notice that `1371995106` occurs twice):

[image: Plot of Linux timestamps]

Actually, since one-second resolution is finer than necessary, but density is important, events that happen at the same time can 'carry over' to the next free second (so it would appear as if the second event that happened at `1371995106` were plotted against the next free second, which is `1371995108`):

[image: Plot of Linux timestamps with better density display]

Can this be plotted using CLI tools in common Linux distros? I have tried `plot` (gnuplot) but been unable to find examples of creating graphs from one-dimensional data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do a frequency plot.  Assuming your data is in a file called data then

```
set format x "%.0f"
set boxwidth .9
set style fill solid
plot 'data' using ($1):(1) smooth frequency title 'Frequency' with boxes
```

`format` stops the label being output with exponents

`boxwidth` sets the width of the box so there's a gap.

The `style` is set to filled boxes

`smooth frequency` sums the `y` values which are set to 1 by the `:(1)` the `x` being the first field in the file `($1)`.